# How get a list of documents IDs the Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter and I have a question, I need to show a list of documents id's on the user screen. My database is the one shown in the image, the data I want to list is the one marked with the blue key. I am trying to retrieve the data with a StreamBuilder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWYp0.png)

I have been searching for information for days but I can't find an answer that solves my problem.

Beforehand I appreciate your attention.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the documents and display the `document.documentID`.

The code below will display the ids in a List view. I hope it helps you

```dart
StreamBuilder(
      stream: firestore.collection("Usuarios").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.data != null){
          QuerySnapshot snap = snapshot.data;
          List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snap.documents;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              DocumentSnapshot doc = documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("${doc.documentID}"),
              );
            },
          );
        }else{
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response to my question, I think I understand the code only one last question, in the code to be referenced with this line:

itemCount: notes.length,

specifically with "notes".

Comment: The `notes` is meant to be `documents`. I've corrected that. sorry

Comment: Don't worry, right now I am trying to implement the solution you proposed to me, but in the following message:

Comment: The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents

Comment: I added some need code to handle the null error. Take a look

Comment: On this occasion I no longer have the message on the console, but nothing appears on the phone screen, it only remains blank. Maybe it's a different problem, like my database?

Comment: Possibly, try printing `doc.documentID` before the return ListTile. if you'll get anything

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I have not managed to make it work properly, the screen is still only blank. However, with the code that you provide me, I think I am one step ahead.

Comment: I correct, your solution works for me, I am very grateful. The problem was in my database.

Comment: nice..happy to help